# Inconsistent prices in Stack Overflow Business forms

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-business

After checking the page https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/engagement I saw that "Scheduling a 15 minute call" box has the following text at the top of the page:

> $10,000 spend minimum to speak to a Sales Rep

Versus the following text at the bottom of the page:

> $5,000 spend minimum to speak to a Sales Rep

I cannot see any difference between the two.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you use the form at the bottom. Looks much cheaper.

Comment: You're right, it's supposed to be $15,000 in both places. Good catch!

Comment: Maybe different scheduling queue? top one could be for premium customers and such

Comment: Nobody gets to the footer of a webpage. The cheaper price is meant as a reward for the brave souls that do.

Comment: I see both as $5.000. Perhaps fixed already?

Comment: $10,000 for 15 minutes of SO's time? Wow. No wonder they ignore Meta.

Comment: You have to pay to talk to somebody that tries to sell you more stuff? Weird.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I think it means that your *account* has to be worth that much.

Comment: Should it perhaps be "$5,000 *ad* spend minimum to speak to a Sales Rep"?

Comment: It least they lie properly elsewhere on the page: "Reach your ideal technical audience". Why would anyone pay $5000 to reach students asking for help with their homework? The high rep users don't see ads.

Comment: @Ludin I see ads - at least job offern and stuff like that. And for ceratin areas 5k for a widespread job advertisement might be ok-ish - "reduced ads" is a 200rep feature - thats not that high: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears both forms now say $5000.

Answer (score 1):

As @jpmc26 noted, this has been updated so both locations have the same pricing.